# Remove previous child nodes when OnChildChanged method called in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store my data. On the Android side I am fetching the data from the Firebase via `firebase::database::ChildListener`. In this child-listener I am using the methods:

```
OnChildAdded(...)
OnChildChanged(...)
```

When my child node is changed on Firebase the change is displayed but previous node which was changed still remain there. Now I have both the previous value and the new changed value.

How can I remove the previous value when my `OnChildAdded` method is called?

Comment: are you maintaining the datas in list ?

Comment: If you are referring to the Android side, then no I am not. @Priya

Comment: in OnChildChanged() - you will get the reference id for the changed value,if you maintained the values in list it will be easy to replace the existing values wit the referenced id you got in OnChildChanged